# How to obtain all the values in a numpy array using an array containing index numbers I want to access

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have the following two numpy arrays. `idxes` contains the indices of the elements I want to be returned from `arr`.

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c' ]
idxes = [1, 2]
// This is the result I'm after
result = ['b', 'c']
```

Initial thoughts were to use `np.where` and a boolean array but it seems pretty awkward to use and was wondering if there's a more elegant solution since I'm quite new to numpy.

Comment: If they are numpy arrays... `arr[idxes]`??

Comment: :O I tried that with my simple example and it works perfectly but for my more complex `arr`, which is an array of numpy arrays with dimension (256, 256, 3) I get a `TypeError: PointSelection __getitem__ only works with bool arrays`. @U10-Forward's solution works for my particular numpy array tho :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this simple list comprehension which iterates through `idxes` and get the value with the index in `idxes` (`i`) in `arr`:

```
print([arr[i] for i in idxes])
```

Output:

```
['b', 'c']
```

If they're numpy arrays:

```
print(arr[idxes])
```

Output:

```
['b' 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
list(map(arr.__getitem__, idxes))
```

Output:

```
['b', 'c']
```